# When will SQLServer 2005 fail to do insert / update AND ALSO WILL NOT "throw" an exception?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

After running a insert or update query against a SQLServer 2005 database, under what scenario (if at all) can this happen - SQLServer 2005 does not perform or fails to perform the insert / update, AND ALSO DOES NOT "THROW" AN EXCEPTION?

Consider that we are running the insert or update query via a SqlCommand object. Also consider that the table against which insert or update query is being used, has

- identity fields
- fields which are not null,
- fields with appropriate data-types
- fields which are reference keys
- fields which have check constraints applied
- etc.

Please assume that in the update query, the "WHERE" condition will find a recrod that needs to be updated.

Can we assume that after we do a SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(), if a insert or update is not performed, then, an un-handled exception will ALLWAYS occur? Otherwise, we can assume that the insert or update query has been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assume that an exception (SqlException) will be thrown UNLESS the INSERT/UPDATE includes a WHERE clause that doesn't match any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the return value of ExecuteNonQuery() to see the number of records affected.

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic to Database stored procedures and throw exceptions(RAISERROR) from there. Then you command(which would call corresponding stored procedure) would have necessary exceptions.